# What is the use of Django's GZip middleware and gzip_page decorator when the web server can apply it?

Tags: python, django, http, web, gzip

Web servers can be configured to compress http response. And Django framework also provides the gzip middleware. My question is:

Which one should I use if I am concerned about performance? And

If both are applied, does it mean the response is compressed twice?

Comment: See relevant thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121608/mod-deflate-vs-django-gzipmiddleware-which-one-to-use-for-deployment.